# Subprocess popen with pushd command

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Hello to whoever reads this. I have spent too long on this issue and exhausted my options. The subprocess docs are quite poor in my opinion and I've read countless stackoverflow questions to no avail. I simply would like to use the pushd command on windows to change directories. Once there, I will want to use communicate() to issue a command. For this examples purpose. I will say that command is dir. I would also like to "pop" back directories but am not sure if that is possible with another communicate method. If anyone can provide any insight, then that would be great. Right now my program is not outputting anything to me. Printing `p.stdout.readline()` is not working either.

```
p = subprocess.Popen([r"pushd", r"C:\MishaMachine"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate('dir')
```

Comment: this will not work. Use the `os.chdir(..)` function to change directories.

Comment: lol. I don't know why I didn't think of that. Looking at the same problem for too long just doesn't help sometimes